# (Unity) Having bad performance of Animator

Tags: performance, animation, unity-game-engine

I am currently working on a 2D Jump and Run game and do a bit of performance testing and optimizations. Ther I came across a big problem. When I load 2500 enemies in my game the script and everything runs smoothly and do not take long, but the animators from those enemies take up round about 33ms and I do not think that this is the way it should behave, because only calling events from animators should not take that long.

Unity version: 2018.1.0f2

I hope somebody can help me with this problem...
[Image of Performance Profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jm2dt.png)

Comment: Rendering 2500 non static enemies is expensive I think this is expected behavior   .

Comment: no just rendering them is not, but the problem as shown in the linked image are the events called from the animators to update to the next sprite only drawing them without animation is not a problem at all, u can see in the profiling that rendering only need a fraction of time(light green part)